# Convert binary to JavaScript? / Convert string to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, binary

I have created a JavaScript test file and converted it to binary.

```
var newElement = document.createElement("h1");
var element = document.createTextNode("Hello World!");
newElement.appendChild(element);
document.body.appendChild(newElement);
```

Converted to:

```
"01110110 01100001 01110010 00100000 01101110 01100101 01110111 01000101 01101100 01100101 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00100000 00111101 00100000 01100100 01101111 01100011 01110101 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00101110 01100011 01110010 01100101 01100001 01110100 01100101 01000101 01101100 01100101 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00101000 00100010 01101000 00110001 00100010 00101001 00111011 00001101 00001010 01110110 01100001 01110010 00100000 01100101 01101100 01100101 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00100000 00111101 00100000 01100100 01101111 01100011 01110101 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00101110 01100011 01110010 01100101 01100001 01110100 01100101 01010100 01100101 01111000 01110100 01001110 01101111 01100100 01100101 00101000 00100010 01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01010111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100 00100001 00100010 00101001 00111011 00001101 00001010 01101110 01100101 01110111 01000101 01101100 01100101 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00101110 01100001 01110000 01110000 01100101 01101110 01100100 01000011 01101000 01101001 01101100 01100100 00101000 01100101 01101100 01100101 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00101001 00111011 00001101 00001010 01100100 01101111 01100011 01110101 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00101110 01100010 01101111 01100100 01111001 00101110 01100001 01110000 01110000 01100101 01101110 01100100 01000011 01101000 01101001 01101100 01100100 00101000 01101110 01100101 01110111 01000101 01101100 01100101 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00101001 00111011"
```

In another JavaScript file I have converted this binary code into a string, but the code does not run.

```
var output = "";
function convertBinary(str) { 
    if(str.match(/[10]{8}/g)){
        var js = str.match(/([10]{8}|\s+)/g).map(function(fromBinary){
            return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(fromBinary, 2) );
        }).join('');
        return console.log(js);
        output = js;
    }
}
var binary = convertBinary("01110110 01100001 01110010 00100000 01101110 01100101 01110111 01000101 01101100 01100101 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00100000 00111101 00100000 01100100 01101111 01100011 01110101 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00101110 01100011 01110010 01100101 01100001 01110100 01100101 01000101 01101100 01100101 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00101000 00100010 01101000 00110001 00100010 00101001 00111011 00001101 00001010 01110110 01100001 01110010 00100000 01100101 01101100 01100101 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00100000 00111101 00100000 01100100 01101111 01100011 01110101 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00101110 01100011 01110010 01100101 01100001 01110100 01100101 01010100 01100101 01111000 01110100 01001110 01101111 01100100 01100101 00101000 00100010 01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01010111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100 00100001 00100010 00101001 00111011 00001101 00001010 01101110 01100101 01110111 01000101 01101100 01100101 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00101110 01100001 01110000 01110000 01100101 01101110 01100100 01000011 01101000 01101001 01101100 01100100 00101000 01100101 01101100 01100101 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00101001 00111011 00001101 00001010 01100100 01101111 01100011 01110101 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00101110 01100010 01101111 01100100 01111001 00101110 01100001 01110000 01110000 01100101 01101110 01100100 01000011 01101000 01101001 01101100 01100100 00101000 01101110 01100101 01110111 01000101 01101100 01100101 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00101001 00111011");

function init() {output};
init();
```

I know the problem is with `function init() {output};` as output is not JavaScript, it is a string.

I have searched and searched, I found how to convert binary to a string, but I cannot find a way to convert a string to actual JavaScript.

can this be done?

Comment: I guess you look for [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: `new Function(output)()`

Comment: You may also wanna turn around the return and output variable. Right now it stops the moment it reaches return. Never changing the output variable. Also I'm not entirely sure if you even wanna do a return of console.log in the first place.

Comment: In the console, the code looks exactly as it does above in the first code block, it does not have have " " around it like a string, so maybe the problem is just the return?

Comment: You wanna do console.log(js); then output = js; and then return js; This way you see the code in console. You update the output variable, and you also return the converted data. But you could also remove output variable, and use binary variable instead. I mean when you do var binary = convertBinary(); then binary gets the return value. No point on having 2 variables (output and binary) with same value, right?

Comment: I have changed `return console.log(js);` to `console.log(js);
        output = js;
        return js;` and I have changed `output` to `eval(output)`

I now get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` in chrome.

Comment: @eddmcmxciii I've tried your code and it works on my machine, can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Does it also say the line number? It should. From your previous, somewhat longer code, I had to beautify it, I noticed a ; missing after console.log("output: " + output). That might've caused it.

Comment: I already spotted the missing ; in chrome console, where it normally says `fileName.js:lineNumber` it says `VM1683: 1`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum A fiddle?

Comment: @eddmcmxciii http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eddmcmxciii/cxq1zedr/1/)

Comment: @eddmcmxciii that's actually a really cute bug in your convertBinary function. It returns `NaN` for every second match (can you tell why?) and when it's `fromCharCode`'d it returns null strings. (which are represented as zero width spaces).

Comment: @eddmcmxciii if we stop matching the empty strings (change the RegExp) it works just fine : https://jsfiddle.net/82j6akro/

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum not sure, in the console log the convertBinary function seems to be working fine, it looks just like it did before I converted it to binary.

Comment: @eddmcmxciii see my later comment, there are zero width spaces between every two characters (because you're matching `" "`s with your RegExp, then `parseInt`ing them into `NaN`s and converting those to chars), removing the `|\s+` part from the RegExp fixes it

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum it worked! but there is an error in the console.log `VM1702:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` when I click on VM1702:2. this shows up `(function() {
[object HTMLHeadingElement]
})`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum fixed that error by using `new function()` instead of `eval(output)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). It explicitly invokes the compiler for you on a string and runs it as JavaScript.

```
eval("alert('hi');"); // evaluates the string and executes it as code
```

As an alternative, you can treat the code as a function body (with arguments) and call [the `Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) on it.

```
var converted = var binary = convertBinary("...");
eval(converted); // run code
var init = Function(converted); // create a function you can later call with the code
```

I don't want to get into *why* you're converting stings this way - if it's an exercise it's good and fun. Keep in mind that files are *already always in binary* and being a *text file* is only a matter *how we look at its contents* and not what its actual contents is.

Comment: Because `eval` makes code terrible slow. Never use it unless you have to. The correct way is `new Function` in this case.

Comment: Thats Exactly what I'm looking for! There may also be an issue with the return on line 7 as @Verkade89 has pointed out.

Comment: @SebastianNette no it doesn't. The reason people say "eval makes code slow" is because they're cargo-culting things they heard years ago. If code is only run _once_ then the performance of `new Function` and `eval` would be exactly the same - the difference is in scoping rules and is irrelevant in this quesiton anyway.

Comment: Run some perfs then. eval runs your code 98% slower. While new Function is the real deal.

Comment: @eddmcmxciii yes, I assumed that was a mistake and you meant to `return` the result and not to log it.

Comment: @SebastianNette I have no idea where you're taking this from, I haven't read the source code of all JS runtimes but I know _for a fact_ that in V8, JavaScriptCode and SpiderMoney performance is exactly the same. Are you sure you're not mixing things up here?

Not that performance is relevant in this case at all, or that the JIT gets to kick in anyway. Meh.

Comment: The reason why eval makes your code run slower is because all intern code optimizations are skipped. Take for example: `function add(a,b) { return a+b; };` and `eval("function addeval(a,b){ return a+b; }");`  http://jsfiddle.net/dqthrw98/ - eval = at least 10 times slower. In more complex functions its far worse.

Comment: @SebastianNette I'm sorry if this comes off the wrong way - but are you deliberately trying to mock me with that benchmark? Is this sarcasm? I don't understand. I tried to provide a useful answer and I don't think I was particularly rude at any point... Anyway, if I change that benchmark a little (still not a good benchmark at all, and doesn't measure addition) http://jsfiddle.net/yn3pnsf1/ you'll notice no difference (since hey, we're not benchmarking scope lookup anymore).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm not saying that your answer is wrong, just that it is not the best answer.

Comment: @SebastianNette ok, then what was the bogus benchmark and speed claims about? I assume you know both do the same thing (call Compiler::GetFunctionFromEval in v8 for example) so the only difference is scoping rules (they pass a different scope argument). Why would you argue that it's slower to call `eval` then?

Comment: By the way - had it _not_ been a single function literal , `eval` would in fact [not call](https://github.com/v8/v8-git-mirror/blob/44ea5fbf9509406ba06274162bf7b8eb36a6ba9a/src/compiler.cc#L1180-L1182) the optimizing compiler here, since this is 4 DOM calls this is all irrelevant anyway. Since your benchmark _is_ in fact a single function literal then the JIT is called anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function, like this:

`eval(output)`

or the [Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), like this:

`var init = new Function(output)
init()`

Comment: I've tried `eval(output)`, I've tried  `var init = new Function(output)` and I've tried `new Function(eval(output))`. It still does not work. I keep getting the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `new Function` for that.
It wraps your code into a function like this:

```
var fn = new Function(output);
fn();
```

Or shorter:

```
new Function(output)();
```

Which is the equivalent of:

```
function(){
    var newElement = document.createElement("h1");
    var element = document.createTextNode("Hello World!");
    newElement.appendChild(element);
    document.body.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## solved!

Binary to JavaScript Converter.

```
var bin = "some binary coded javascript"
var output = "";
function convertBinary(str) { 
    if(str.match(/[10]{8}/g)){
        var js = str.match(/([10]{8})/g).map(function(fromBinary){
            return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(fromBinary, 2) );
        }).join('');
        //console.log(js);
        output = js;
        return js;
    }
}
var binary = convertBinary(bin);
var init = new Function(output);
init();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function binaryAgent(str) {
  //every ' ' split the string and put it into an array
  var arr = str.split(' ');

  //for every value in the array move it to base 2 (unicode) and convert it
  for (var i in arr) {
    var c = parseInt(arr[i], 2);
    arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(c);
  }

  return str = arr.join('');

}
```